# Keypress not responding to "f" click

Tags: jquery, keypress

The following code logs every character I can think to click *unless* I click the "f" key. My "f" key obviously works in general because I managed to type this. So, is there any other reason this might happen?

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
  console.log("keypress", e);
});
```

Comment: Fiddle seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/4c6dv8qu/. Problem must be somewhere else. Try to make a fiddle that reproduces the issue.

Comment: No "F"-aks was given that day... Maybe someone hijacks your event and prevents that event further?

Comment: What the uck!... Are you sure you aren't preventing 'f' key keypress event to propagate inside other bound handler?

Comment: I can't think of any reason in the whole world that I would have decided to  prevent the propagation of the "f" keypress elsewhere in the project. However, just because I didn't do it, doesn't mean someone else didn't... I'll start hunting.